# PowerShell scope clash when dot sourcing scripts

Tags: powershell, scope

I'm having some scope issues when dot sourcing powershell scripts.
Suppose I have one script 'A.ps1':

```
$VERSION = "1.0"

# Dot source B.ps1
. .\B.ps1

function Write-Version { Write-Host "A.ps1 version $VERSION" }
Write-Version
```

And a script B.ps1

```
$VERSION = "2.0"
function Write-Version { Write-Host "B.ps1 version $VERSION" }
Write-Version
```

The output of running A.ps1 will be:

```
B.ps1 version 2.0
A.ps1 version 2.0
```

Why this happens is quite obvious. The `$VERSION` variable from B.ps1 is put into the scope of A.ps1 and overwrites that variable. Indeed, this happens with `Write-Version` as well, but here A.ps1 overwrites B's version, but because `Write-Version` is called in B.ps1 before that happens, we can still see the output of B's Write-Version function.

The question, of course, is how to prevent this?? I've tried various scope options, but this doesn't seem to work when dot-sourcing. And since there are functions in B.ps1 that I do need in A's scope, just invoking B.ps1 is probably not an option.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Interesting question.  If it were me I would not reuse the same variable name in both scripts if they are used in the same session...

Comment: Everything about your question is valid and so are both answers (that you should use modules) -- **except for your premise**. You state that B outputs 2.0 and A outputs 1.0. (If that were in fact true, you would have no need to have even posted the question!) In reality, A outputs 2.0, which is your whole point. ( Yes, I know it is just a typo, but what a difference one character makes :-)

Comment: @msorens Yes, thank you for spotting that. You're absolutely correct in your reasoning. I'll modify the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by making B.ps1 a module and renaming it to B.psm1. Add `Export-ModuleMember` to make your functions available to other scripts.

This would be B.psm1:

```
$VERSION = "2.0"
function Write-Version { Write-Host "B.ps1 version $VERSION" }
Write-Version

# Only items specified here will be exported. If Export-ModuleMember is not used,
# ALL members (functions, variables, and aliases) will be exported. In this case
# if $VERSION was exported, $VERSION will be set to "2.0" in script A.ps1
Export-ModuleMember -Function Write-Version
```

And A.ps1 would be:

```
$VERSION = "1.0"

# Import B.psm1
Import-Module .\B.psm1

function Write-Version { Write-Host "A.ps1 version $VERSION" }
Write-Version

# Use B.psm1's `Write-Version` function
B\Write-Version
```

Comment: Some helpful information about Export-ModuleMember than can prevent confusion in trying to figure out why specific things aren't being imported: _If a script module does not include an Export-ModuleMember command, the functions in the script module are exported, but the variables and aliases are not. When a script module includes an Export-ModuleMember command, only the members specified in the Export-ModuleMember command are exported._

Comment: Good point! Thanks for making note of that. I'll add a comment to the example.

Answer (score 3):

Modules were created in Powershell V2 to address these kinds of issues with dot sourcing. Save your script with a psm1 extension and use the Import-Module cmdlet instead of dot sourcing in the code.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll mark Rynant's answer because it has a little more information. I wish I could mark both though.

Answer (score 1):

As guys abouve mentioned one of the solution is to convert your script to PS Module.

But, as soon as you don't need to dot-source functions in functions to global source (I face that problem and not sure if there is a way to solve it: [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187510/dot-sourcing-functions-from-file-to-global-scope-inside-of-function)) you can solve your issue this way:

ScopesA.ps1:

```
$VERSION = "1.0"
$overridenFromAntotherFile = "original"

# Invoke ScopesB.ps1 via &
& .\ScopesB.ps1

Function Write-Version { Write-Host "ScopesA.ps1 version $VERSION" }
Write-Version

Write-Host $overridenFromAntotherFile
```

ScopesB.ps1:

```
$VERSION = '2.0'
$global:overridenFromAntotherFile = 'overriden'
function Write-Version { Write-Host "ScopesB.ps1 version $VERSION" }
Write-Version
```

Output:

```
ScopesB.ps1 version 2.0
ScopesA.ps1 version 1.0
overriden
```

The idea is to use & invocation instead of dot-sourcing (you can read about them in my [article](http://personal-code.blogspot.com/2012/08/one-character-drama.html) but it is not much to say more than & invokes something without adding it to current scope and . invokes and adds to scope).

And still, you can access your global scope from ScopeB.ps1 via scope modifier (this is also mentioned in [same article](http://personal-code.blogspot.com/2012/08/one-character-drama.html) with examples). This is explained with **$overridenFromAntotherFile** variable in script above.