# Dot-sourcing functions from file to global scope inside of function

Tags: powershell

I want to import external function from file, not converting it to a module (we have hundreds of file-per-function, so treat all them as modules is overkill).

Here is code explanation. Please notice that I have some additional logic in Import-Function like adding scripts root folder and to check file existence and throw special error, to avoid this code duplication in each script which requires that kind of import.

C:\Repository\Foo.ps1:

```
Function Foo {
    Write-Host 'Hello world!'
}
```

C:\InvocationTest.ps1:

```
# Wrapper func
Function Import-Function ($Name) {
    # Checks and exception throwing are omitted
    . "C:\Repository\$name.ps1"

    # Foo function can be invoked in this scope
}

# Wrapped import
Import-Function -Name 'Foo'
Foo          # Exception: The term 'Foo' is not recognized

# Direct import
. "C:\Repository\Foo.ps1"
Foo          # 'Hello world!'
```

Is there any trick, to dot source to global scope?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't make the script run in a parent scope, but you can create a function in the global scope by explicitly scoping it.

Would something like this work for you?

```
# Wrapper func
Function Import-Function ($Path) {
    # Checks and exception throwing are omitted
    $script = Get-Content $Path
    $Script -replace '^function\s+((?!global[:]|local[:]|script[:]|private[:])[\w-]+)', 'function Global:$1'
    .([scriptblock]::Create($script))

}
```

[The above regex](https://regex101.com/r/wT1vE2/1) only targets root functions (functions left justified; no white space to left of the word `function`). In order to target all functions, regardless of spacing (including sub-functions), change the `$Script -replace` line to:

```
$Script -replace '^\s*function\s+((?!global[:]|local[:]|script[:]|private[:])[\w-]+)','function Global:$1'
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this nice hach is working. I added few minor fixes to make it work, if you don't mind.

Comment: Don't mind at all.  I was just trying to convey an idea, not necessarily a complete finished solution.

Comment: @AntonPurin can you update the answer to include your 'minor fixes'?

Comment: Anton did.  The posted solution is updated with the fixes he added for his application.

Comment: Great start. RegEx still needed some work, so [I made another edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13698148). Thanks for the great starting point!

Comment: This is great, but I ran into the problem described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35489827/sourcing-a-scriptblock-results-in-different-behavior-than-sourcing-a-file. The solution is to set ``$OFS = "`r`n"`` so that when you Get-Content on a file that has comments, it doesn't comment out all your code

Answer (score 5):

You can change the functions that are defined in the dot-sourced files so that they are defined in the global scope:

```
function Global:Get-SomeThing {
    # ...
}
```

When you dot source that from within a function, the function defined in the dot sourced file will be global. Not saying this is best idea, just another possibility.

Answer (score 4):

Just dot-source the function as well:

```
. Import-Function -Name 'Foo'
Foo # Hello world!
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember a way to run a function in global scope right now. You could do something like this:

```
$name = "myscript"

$myimportcode= {
    # Checks and exception throwing are omitted
    . .\$name.ps1
    # Foo function can be invoked in this scope
}

Invoke-Expression -Command $myimportcode.ToString()
```

When you convert the scriptblock to a string `.ToString()`, the variable will expand.