# Sourcing a ScriptBlock results in different behavior than sourcing a file

Tags: powershell

I'd like to be able to source a ScriptBlock that has script scope functions in it and use them in my calling script without having to prefix every call with "script:".   Stuff I read implies that sourcing a ScriptBlock is the same as sourcing the same content from a file but when I source it from a file I can call the functions in that sourced code without using the "script:" prefix.  When sourcing the same content from a ScriptBlock I can only use the sourced functions if I prefix the calls with "script:".

```
     function Src-Adjusted-ToolsLibrary {
        $Script = get-content "$(split-path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)\Library.ps1"
        $Script = $Script -ireplace '\s*function\s(\w+)','function script:$1'
        #. ([scriptBlock]::Create($Script))  #not working the same as dot sourcing a file because
                                             #when I do this I can only call functions by prefixing
                                             #then with "script:"  like  "$out=(script:foo 'arg1')

        #Invoke-Expression $Script           #same issue

        #only by saving the data into a temp file and sourcing it am I able to call functions without
        #prefixing the call with "script:".   This works:   "$out=(foo 'arg1)"
        $tmpfile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()+'.ps1'
        $Script > $tmpfile
            . $tmpfile
            Remove-Item -Force $tmpfile

    }
```

Resolved-The real problem was that when I read the code in with Get-Content it was in the form of an array that was joined together into one long line while passing it into [ScriptBlock]::Create($script), consequently the first '#' in the header of my source script commented out the entire script. I was initially thinking the problem was an ScriptBlock scoping anomaly but the scoping issues were probably a side effect of using powershell_ide and objects remaining in my environment.  So basically all I needed to do was to set the output field separator to "`r`n" before feeding $Script into [ScriptBlock]::Create.  Below is the corrected code:

```
    function Src-Adjusted-ToolsLibrary {
        $lib="$(split-path $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)\Library.ps1"
        if ( -Not (Test-Path $lib) ) {throw "$lib not found!"}
        $Script = get-content $lib
        $script = $Script -ireplace 'global','script'
        $ofs="`r`n"
        . ([scriptBlock]::Create($Script))
    }
```

Comment: Are you calling those dot-sourced functions inside the `Src-Adjusted-ToolsLibrary` function or in the parent scope?

Comment: No.  But I did test that scenario.  When sourcing the ScriptBlockI still had to prefix the function calls with "script:".    Note that because I'm sourcing the library file in a function, I  do a regex replace to put all the library functions into the "script" scope.  Otherwise, the sourced files would have been in the functions local scope.  I just don't understand why I have to use the "script:" scope qualifier everywhere that I use the library functions if I sourced the library as a ScriptBlock and not when I sourced it as a file?

Comment: Script file create their own `script` scope. `ScriptBlock` does not.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks, good to know. Is there any docs on this or it's just a fact from experience? Jason, if you want to do what I think you want to do, try my [Import-Component](https://github.com/beatcracker/Powershell-Misc/blob/master/Import-Component.ps1) function and see [complementing blog post](https://beatcracker.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/writing-stealth-code-in-powershell/) fro details.

Comment: @beatcracker [`Get-Help about_Scopes`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847849.aspx): *Script: The scope that is created while a script file runs.*

Comment: @PetSerAl "Script file create their own script scope. ScriptBlock does not".  Are you saying when you dot source a file it creates it's own scope and sourcing a ScriptBlock does not?   Sourcing a file seems to integrate nicely into the current scripts "script" scope, whereas sourcing a ScriptBlock seemed to require me to explicitly specify the "script" scope.

Comment: I'm not sure yet  but I also think I'm seeing issues with #'s in files that I read via get-content and convert to a ScriptBlock.

Comment: If I put a '#' comment anywere in my Library.ps1 file it seems to comment out from the # to the end of the file.  If I use <# #> comments it works as expected.  I think that reading the file with get-content and turning it into a ScriptBlock makes it so that the it acts like one long line so that a '#' comments all the way to the end of the file.

Comment: FIX:  I was wrong about the scoping anomaly.   I can't exactly explain why I thought I was seeing the behavior that I described.   Weird things happen when developing in powershell_ise as functions and variables exist from one execution to the nextr.  Ultimately the problem was that when reading in a file with get-content each line becomes an element of an array.  When I used [ScriptBlock]::Create($script) the array was being converted to one long string and losing it's line separators.   So the fix was to set the output field separator like so $ofs="`r`n" before converting to a ScriptBlock.

Comment: You can use `Get-Content -Raw` (PS 3.0) or `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($PathToFile)` to read file as one string.